# The remote server returned an error (405). Method Not Allowed?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-7-x64, .net-4.5

My wcf service is returing the error

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

while looking others answer found that we have to configure it in windows features.

My application is in framework 4.5.1, but when i open windows features tab, The `.net 4.5 advanced services` is not listed there

How do i resolve this.

Comment: Is this a SOAP or a REST service ?

Comment: Also, what is the version of IIS that you use ?